# Group rows of data by 3 columns and sum another column within respective groups

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array, sum, grouping

I have the php array like this:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (            
            [time_stamp] => 1287484988
            [date_time] => Tuesday, 19 October 2010 16:13:7
            [day] => 19
            [month] => 10
            [year] => 2010
            [time_spent] => 41
        )

    [1] => Array
        (         
            [time_stamp] => 1287484662
            [date_time] => Tuesday, 19 October 2010 16:7:41
            [day] => 19
            [month] => 10
            [year] => 2010
            [time_spent] => 215           
        )
)
```

Suppose in january the total number of days is: 31

How do I loop through the number of days(31) to get the SUM of time_spent(time_spent for every day for a given month) using `GROUP BY` time_stamp  where `day=$day,month=$month,year=$year`  using php.

Comment: If you're getting this array data from a database query, you could get the database query itself to return the sums for you

Comment: Because the array i stored in memcache. so i need looping through normal array

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The basic version would be

```
$sums = array();

foreach ($your_array as $entry) {
   if (!isset($sums[$entry['year']]) {
        $sums[$entry['year']] = array();
   }
   if (!isset($sums[$entry['year']][$entry['month']]) {
        $sums[$entry['year']][$entry['month']] = array();
   }
   if (!isset($sums[$entry['year']][$entry['month']][$entry['day']]) {
        $sums[$entry['year']][$entry['month']][$entry['day']] = 0;
   }

   $sums[$entry['year']][$entry['month']][$entry['day']] += $entry['time_spent'];
}
```

Ugly, but the 3 `if()` prevent various warnings from being spit out as the `$sums` array is built.

Comment: thanks u r reply. But i need total time_spent of a given month (day wise time_spent for a given month)

Comment: In that case, just eliminate the day portion and sum up purely by year/month.

Answer (score 0):

When using square brace syntax to create child elements, it is not necessary to instantiate its parent element(s).

Use the date values as a path keys and add the new value to the cached value.  If it encountered for the first time default to 0.

Code: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/sZaYs))

```
$result = [];
foreach ($array as $row) {
    extract($row);
    $result[$year][$month][$day] = ($result[$year][$month][$day] ?? 0) + $time_spent;
}
var_export($result);
```

---

If you wish to build a flat array, you can concatenate the columnar data to form composite string keys.

```
$result["$year$month$day"] = ($result["$year$month$day"] ?? 0) + $time_spent;
```